# Gson TypeAdapter and serializeNulls

Tags: java, gson

I'm using Gson 2.4.

`Gson` has a flag whether null values should be serialized or omitted (the default).
When I create a `TypeAdapter` from a `Gson` which omits nulls and serialize an object via the `TypeAdapter` then this flag is ignored, contradicting the [Javadoc](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html):

> Type adapters should be prepared to read null from the stream and
>   write it to the stream. (...) If your Gson
>   instance has been configured to GsonBuilder.serializeNulls(), these
>   nulls will be written to the final document. **Otherwise the value (and
>   the corresponding name when writing to a JSON object) will be omitted
>   automatically.** In either case your type adapter must handle null.

Here is a test which demonstrates the problem:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test {
    private String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test object = new Test();
        Gson gson = new Gson(); // serializeNulls is off by default

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(object));
        System.out.println(gson.getAdapter(Test.class).toJson(object));
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
{}
{"name":null}
```

I expected that the second line is `{}`.

Is this a bug or did I misread the documentation? In both cases: Is there are a workaround to omit nulls when serializing via a `TypeAdapter`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `TypeAdapter` doesn't do the actual raw serialization. It defers to a `JsonWriter` which it receives in its `write` method. So the actual check for `null` is done in the `JsonWriter`'s various `name`/`value` calls (for JSON objects).

The `JsonWriter` maintains a `serializeNulls` flag (among others). When using `Gson#toJson`, the `Gson` object will create a new `JsonWriter` and overwrite its `serializeNulls` value with its own and pass that `JsonWriter` to whatever `TypeAdapter` it decides to use.

In your second case, the `TypeAdapter#toJson` call is creating a new `JsonWriter` with default values. The javadoc of [`JsonWriter#setSerializeNulls`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html#setSerializeNulls%28boolean%29) states

> Sets whether object members are serialized when their value is null.
>   This has no impact on array elements. **The default is `true`**.

That's the behavior you see.

You could create your own `JsonWriter` and configure it appropriately and pass it to the overloaded [`toJson(Writer, T)`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html#toJson%28java.io.Writer,%20T%29) method.

I think the javadoc statement applies to the use of `TypeAdapter` objects through `Gson` objects.